# If A is a symmetric n × n matrix, what does $x^TAx = 1$ have at least one solution imply? x is a column vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm wondering that what does the equation $x^TAx = 1$ have at least one solution tell about A if A is a symmetric n × n matrix? (x is a column vector)

Comment: If $A$ is not negative semidefinite, such a $x$ always exists...

Comment: Does A need to be invertible?

Comment: Nope. $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: A symmetric matrix can always be diagonalized, so you can choose such basis in $\Bbb{R}^n$ that makes $A$ diagonal. The rest is easy.